# Mongodb positional operator " $ " with $sum operation not working

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm working on an e-commerce web app, I use MEAN stack.
I have a collection for orders, each order has a `payment` field which has subdocuments for payment data for (`affiliate marketer`, `sellersPayment`, `website`, `referral`)
my question is about the `sellersPayment` field, I have an array like

```
      sellersPayment: [
        {
          amount: 50,
          isPaid: false,
          seller: ObjectId('seller 1 id'),
        },
        {
          amount: 80,
          isPaid: true,
          seller: ObjectId('seller 2 id'),
        },
      ]
```

the thing is I want to query orders which has a specific seller on the field `seller` inside that array ant then sum the `amount` field
this is my approach:

```
    await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          "payment.sellersPayment": {
            $elemMatch: {
              seller: ObjectId(user._id),
              isPaid: false,
            },
          },
        }      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          confirmedBalance: { $sum: "$payment.sellersPayment.$.amount" },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          confirmedBalance: 1,
        },
      },
    ]);
```

I get this error

> " FieldPath field names may not start with '$' "
> any solutions ?

Comment: Can you provide an input and output example? Also, you can't use two positional operator `$`. Try removing one of them in `"$payment.sellersPayment.$.amount"`

Comment: thanks a lot, I marked the last comment as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I get this error " FieldPath field names may not start with '$' " any solutions ?*
>
> `confirmedBalance: { $sum: "$payment.sellersPayment.$.amount" },`

This is the invalid syntax, you can not use $ sign to access array elements,

There are few fixes,

- `$match` you condition is correct
- `$unwind` deconstruct `sellersPayment` array
- `$match` match again your first stage condition to filter subdocument of `sellersPayment`
- `$group` by null and sum amount using field `payment.sellersPayment.amount`
- `$project` to show required fields

```
await Order.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "payment.sellersPayment": {
        $elemMatch: {
          seller: ObjectId(user._id),
          isPaid: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$payment.sellersPayment" },
  {
    $match: {
      "payment.sellersPayment.seller": ObjectId(user._id),
      "payment.sellersPayment.isPaid": false
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      confirmedBalance: { $sum: "$payment.sellersPayment.amount" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      confirmedBalance: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YNWGuVrTqeA)